# PHP won't post to next file from drop down list

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

Im creating a database using PHP and SQL to store peoples current locations. For one of the pages I am loading in all possible locations from the SQL database and putting it into a drop down list. Once the user submits the location that they want, it to supossed to POST to the next PHP file where the query will take place however it fails to do this.

```
<form action=droplocationget.php method="post">
<?php
$server = 'XXXXXXXX';
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"XXXXXXX");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);

$Getloc = "SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM CurrentData";
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $Getloc);

  echo "<select id='location' name='location'>";
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
echo "<option value=''>".$row['location']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type = "submit" value="Find">
</form>
```

And the recieving code is:

```
?php
$server = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"XXXXXXX");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);

$NewLocation = "'". $_POST['Location']."'";



$describeQuery="select Username, Firstname, Lastname, Location from 
CurrentData WHERE Location = $NewLocation";
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo '<p>'.$row['Username'].' '.$row['Firstname'].' '.$row['Lastname'].' 
'.$row['Location'].'</p>';
}

sqlsrv_close($conn)
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `$NewLocation = "'". $_POST['Location']."'";`

It should be a lowercase "`l`" (L) because of `name='location'` which is case-sensitive.

And then changing that to simply `$NewLocation = $_POST['location'];` and then quote the value for it in the query's `WHERE` clause.

I.e.:

```
WHERE Location = '$NewLocation'";
```

Given if it is a string, which most likely is.

Side note: It's always best to always terminate all statements.

```
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

and also quote the action

```
action="droplocationget.php"
```

PHP's error reporting would have been of help.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Side note:

If you want a value to appear (and in HTML source) you can use `'".$value."'` as an example.

```
echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$row['location']."</option>";
```

The value can be anything, it can even be the same value used for `$row` or another column's value.

If you want that value to be set (appear) in double quotes, then simply escape the double quotes:

```
echo "<option value=\"$value\">".$row['location']."</option>";
```

Some prefer having double quoted values.

---

Note that the column names and values are (also) case-sensitive.

As per shown in comments, that the populated rows should be with an uppercase `L`.

```
echo "<option value='".$row['Location']."'>".$row['Location']."</option>";
```

as per the query's column name being `Location`.

Comment: I added a variable to the droplocationget.php to see if the $_POST is returning a value and it is empty 

I.e:

$NewLocation = $_POST['location']

   echo "NEW LOCATION IS... $NewLocation";

And the output is empty so I think my Droplist is broken

Comment: @Clarky check for errors on the query then. and reload my answer; I edited it a few times. You will need to reload it.

Comment: Thanks fot your help

Comment: @Clarky I made a few more edits, if you want to see them, reload the answer and look under **Side note** near the bottom. Just in case you wish to have that, *cheers*

Comment: Could my problem be that although the locations are shown as an option on the drop down, that they hold no value, as I am still left with an empty $_POST?

Comment: @Clarky Yes, just as my edits show. You can use whichever value is needed and modify accordingly.

Comment: @Clarky Also view your HTML source during testing, you will see what passes in the option(s).

Comment: Im sorry if Im wasting your time at this point but how can I set the option value equal to that of the location that is returned from the SQL database

Comment: @Clarky No worries; try `echo "<option value='".$row['location']."'>".$row['location']."</option>";` - that ought to work. Again; look at your HTML source, it will show you what's being passed in the value for it.

Comment: @Clarky or `echo "<option value='".$row['Location']."'>".$row['Location']."</option>";` with an uppercase `L` given what the query is, where you have `Location` as it too stands to be case-sensitive.

Comment: IT WORKS, Thanks you have saved me a long night!

Comment: @Clarky *hehe* cool!! glad to have been of help, *cheers*  and you're most welcome :-)